# При работе с VK SDK нет некоторых методов и классов

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь разобраться с API vk, до этого никогда не работал с API из соц сетей. Не могу понять, почему подчеркивает строчки. Пользуюсь уроком [вот этим](http://interosite.ru/articles/rabota-s-api-vkontakte-v-android). Там есть строки вида (коммент — это то, что мне пишет):

```
VKUIHelper.onCreate(this); // Can not resolve method onCreate
VKUIHelper.onResume(this); // Can not resolve method onResume
VKUIHelper.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); // Can not resolve method onActivityResult
VKUIHelper.onDestroy(this); // Can not resolve method onDestroy
```

Comment: https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/issues/134 а вообще что бы работать с примером используйте старую версию. `compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.3.9'`

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish ааа... вот блин, а я столько парился. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема вызвана дефолтным указанием в `build.gradle` последней версии библиотеки, в которой нет обратной совместимости, а пример используемый в вопросе использует код старой версии.

Итого, для корректной работы кода нужно использовать старую версию библиотеки:

```
compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.3.9'
```

*Согласно комменту @SorryForMyEnglish*